# Create new Azure Function App without deleting existing Azure Functions in Resource Group

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-function-app

I have a resource group that already has some function apps. I now want to use Terraform to deploy more function apps in the same resource group. The problem is when I run Terraform plan it tells me that the previous resources will be deleted and the new ones will be created. I want to leave the previous resources as they are. I have copied my code below. The result of Terraform plan is 5 resources created and 5 deleted.

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "location" {
  type = string
}

variable "resource_name" {
  type = string
}

resource "random_string" "random" {
  length = 9
  special = false
  number = true
  upper = false
}

variable "storage_account_tier" {
  type = string
  default = "Standard"
}

variable "storage_account_type" {
  type = string
  default = "LRS"
}

variable "service_plan_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "service_plan_tier" {
  type = string
  default = "Standard"
}

variable "service_plan_size" {
  type = string
  default = "S1"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = replace(join(",",["storageaccount",random_string.random.result]),",","")
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = var.storage_account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.storage_account_type
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = var.service_plan_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku {
    tier = var.service_plan_tier
    size = var.service_plan_size
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                      = var.resource_name
  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id       = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string
}
```

Comment: What does the plan look like? And can you edit your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the issue?

Comment: The plan says 5 resources created and 5 deleted. I cannot attach images unfortunately.

Comment: Copy and paste the text into your question. Don't do it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on Terraform for creating infrastructure on AWS and resolved this issue with aws resources. If you can paste your `terraform plan` output in reply, i might be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
```

You're telling Terraform that you want it to completely manage that resource group.

If you want to leave a pre-existing resource group alone but still reference its properties, do

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"
```

and then instead of referencing the properties like:

```
azurerm_resource_group.example.location
```

replace that with:

```
data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
```